# Placeholder for input type="text" with Bootstrap data-rule="quantity"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

everyone!

Is there a way to have a placeholder for `<input type="text" data-rule="quantity">`? I tried putting the property `placeholder="Placeholder here"`, but it did not work.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="input-group spinner" data-trigger="spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" data-placeholder="Quantity" data-rule="quantity" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon rmv-grp-addon">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-up" data-spin="up"><div class="caret-up"></div></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-down" data-spin="down"><div class="caret-down"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looking forward for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using data-placeholder="Quantity"??? Instead use only placeholder

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Quantity" data-rule="quantity" required>
```

Refer - http://plnkr.co/edit/SX9A1xDq26QhDOjs6jNo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Placeholder here" data-placeholder="Quantity" data-rule="quantity" required>
```

Change it to this. It will working